# How should I implement `OnLoad` event handler when creating an activity using a contact?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've created my own solution with a custom entity of type activity. I'd like to show a message whenever a new instance of it is created **using an existing contact** but not allow the user to create one, if **only attempting to do that without going via contact**.

Basically, my aim is that it won't be impossible to just create that activity (the form will be hidden directly at any attempt except for one way only). The user will have to go to contacts (or leads etc.) and in there add and create an instance of the custom activity entity. That way, I can assure that the field "regarding" will be filled out already.

I'm guessing that I need to detect somehow that the opening of the form is a creation attempt. How can I do that?

Also, as it is now, the user can't create a contact-less activity of the custom type because it doesn't appear on the menu with other activities. I must have disabled it somehow but I have no idea how. Anybody who has one?

Comment: In other words, this activity can't exist in the system without a reference to a Contact or a Lead?

Comment: Exactly right! But I think I'll solve it by just requiring the field to be filled. I might have complicated things unnecessarily. But just for the future reference - how would I close such a window if it's a creation time **but** the field isn't set? (The condition, I've got, but closing the window by force is a bit unclear to me...

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do this in javascript, similar to what Andreas mentioned, but since this is a system rule, I would just emphasize the importance of duplicating client logic with server-side logic via plugins, which hasn't unfortunately been addressed in an answer yet.

Comment: Server side on CRM?! We're not allowed into the back-system, are we? There's only a few DLLs that SDK permits us to use, no DOM-touching, no access to DB (even looking into it is a frown-maker, I understand)... And you suggest that I program the server? One of us has missed something (statistically, it's me, hehe).

Comment: Heh, [per Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx), "A plug-in is custom business logic (code) that you can integrate with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online to modify or augment the standard behavior of the platform. Another way to think about plug-ins is that they are handlers for events fired by Microsoft Dynamics CRM. You can subscribe, or register, a plug-in to a known set of events to have your code run when the event occurs." The are plenty of samples in the SDK and many questions that address plug-in development @ SO.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about C#, aren't you? I misunderstood and thought that you were suggesting that we put in JS into the server part that produces the HTML-content or something like that. In such case - yes, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Mr Wood, I'd like to show you some code. It works as supposed to but I'm not sure if it's optimal.

```js
var foo = function () {

  var whatIsGoingOn = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();

  if (whatIsGoingOn === 1)
    alert("Let there be an entity!");
  else
    alert("Not a creation...");
}
```

The other states' (deletion, update etc.) numeric values are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this a bunch of ways but the easiest would probably be to:

- Make the regarding field read only.
- Make the regarding field mandatory.

That way if a user opens a create new form they wont be able to set the regarding and because its mandatory they wont be able to save the record. When they open via an existing contact the regarding field will be mapped automatically. That said in this case just making it mandatory my be enough.

([As a side JavaScript can be used to identify the current form state](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/crm-2011-using-javascript-to-identifying-if-a-form-is-in-create-or-update-contect/), but I'm not sure how useful that is here).

In terms of where custom activities appear, by default mine show in a number of locations, for example:

- CRM > Workplace > Activities > Ribbon > Other Activities > XXX.
- CRM > Workplace > Activities > View Selector > XXX.

They don't show under the left hand navigation of the workplace because they are grouped under 'Activities'. I'm pretty sure these are all the default settings.

You can exercise greater control by editing the sitemap, where you can put pretty much anything, anywhere.

Comment: I was thinking of making the "*regarding*" field required **but** I'm going to get some data to present in a `picklist` for user to choose from as they create a new custom activity. That data depends on the type of the entity in "*regarding*" field (different set of options for contact, for lead for account etc.). So, it feels smoother to simply prohibit the user from creating the activity "the wrong way". Otherwise I'll have to add a script that updates/changes the `picklist` eachtime `onChange` is fired from "*regarding*" field.

Comment: +1 for the read-only + required (mandatory) approach, that is what I was thinking. You could then also add an onLoad script to see if Regarding field has data. If it does not, hide all sections on the form and reveal just one which had a display name of "you need to create this activity from a Contact or Lead record" (with no fields in, you're just using the section label to display some text, you could of course use an Alert instead, but that forces the user to do another click to dismiss it)

Comment: That all said, its not much more work to create a dependant picklist in any case, especially if you are doing it for the onload. The onchange shouldnt be any different. Write one function that onload removes the invalid options based on the current regarding. Then onchange call that function again.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part of your question:

When you create a custom activity you can choose whether to have it appear in 'normal' Activity menus or not by checking the box at the top right of the entity form. This is a once-only choice as far as I know and can't be changed later.

For your setup, I would suggest NOT checking this box, so it does not appear in the activity menus to avoid users even being tempted to do it that way.

Instead, add an explicit relationship to the activity N:1 to Contact, and another N:1 to Lead. Use this relationship to add your activity to the left navigation of Contact and Lead forms, or add a grid for them (depends on how you want to use this and if you need to filter the view to something other than the default "Associated View").

When a user navigates to this section they will see if any previous activities of this type exist, and be able to add a new one. BUT this means that the child record is a child via this relationship, not using "regarding", so use a script on the form for the activity so that if Contact is filled in, it is copied to Regarding, and if Lead is filled in then that is copied.  If neither, then use an alert or other means to warn the use that something is wrong (see comment earlier). If you want Regarding to be read-only but filled in by script, you will need to make sure to use the force the value to be saved:

```javascript
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").setSubmitMode("always");
```

You must have the lookups for Contact and Lead on the form to be able to use them in your scripts, but you can make them not "visible by default" so they are there but not seen by the user (and taking up no space).

Comment: How should I handle the other kinds of entities? It'll be a bit limiting if I'll have to add a new 1:M relationship for an account and a whatever-kind-a-customer-have-added. Can that be made general?

Comment: Not easily, that is what the "regarding" lookup field is for to provide the generality, but if you want to hide your custom activity from the normal menus then users won't be able to create a new record down the 'regarding' relationship.
You could use a custom button on the Ribbon to fire some javascript to do the job, I'm pretty sure I have seen examples which pop a record form and pre-fill some of the fields based on defaults or data from the parent record.

Comment: Cool. Luckily for me, we've decided to allow the users to do it in both ways, so that problem is gone. Nevertheless, very interesting set of suggestions.